# client-go: watch.RetryWatcher: How to obtain a stream of resource changes with monotonically increasing resource versions?

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I need to react to changes to CRs inside a K8s cluster, and have created the following PoC.

Running the program yields the following output after creating a new pod `kubectl run NAME --image=nginx --restart=Never`.

**Output**:

```
$ go run ./cmd/watcher/                                                                               
- ADDED: test [94926364]
- MODIFIED: test [94926365]
- MODIFIED: test [94926368]
- MODIFIED: test [94926387]
- ADDED: test [94926387]
- ADDED: test [94926387]
- ADDED: test [94926387]
```

Why is the same `ADDED` event emitted multiple times? Furthermore, if I remove the code to skip "old" events, then I see `ADDED` events for all running pods?

**Code**:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/unstructured"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/schema"
    apiWatch "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/watch"
    "k8s.io/client-go/dynamic"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/watch"
)

func main() {
    configLoader := clientcmd.NewNonInteractiveDeferredLoadingClientConfig(
        clientcmd.NewDefaultClientConfigLoadingRules(),
        &clientcmd.ConfigOverrides{},
    )
    // Determine the namespace referenced by the
    // current context in the kubeconfig file.
    namespace, _, err := configLoader.Namespace()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // `rest.Config`` holds the common attributes that can
    // be passed to a Kubernetes client on initialization.
    cfg, err := configLoader.ClientConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    dc, err := dynamic.NewForConfig(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    WatchPods(dc, namespace)
}

type watcher struct {
    client      *dynamic.DynamicClient
    timeoutSecs int64
}

func newWatcher(dc *dynamic.DynamicClient, timeout int64) cache.Watcher {
    return &watcher{dc, timeout}
}

func (w *watcher) Watch(options metav1.ListOptions) (apiWatch.Interface, error) {
    // identify resource
    gvr := schema.GroupVersionResource{
        Group:    "",
        Version:  "v1",
        Resource: "pods",
    }

    return w.client.Resource(gvr).Watch(context.Background(), metav1.ListOptions{
        Watch:          true,
        TimeoutSeconds: &w.timeoutSecs,
    })
}

var _ cache.Watcher = (*watcher)(nil)

func WatchPods(dc *dynamic.DynamicClient, namespace string) {
    w := newWatcher(dc, 50)
    rw, err := watch.NewRetryWatcher("1", w)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for {
        event, ok := <-rw.ResultChan()
        
        if !ok {
            fmt.Println("Channel closed")
            continue
        }

        pod, ok := event.Object.(*unstructured.Unstructured)
        
        if !ok {
            continue
        }

        // Skip resource changes older than 5 minutes
        creationTime := pod.GetCreationTimestamp().Time
        fiveMinsAgo := time.Now().Add(-5 * time.Minute)

        if creationTime.Before(fiveMinsAgo) {
            continue
        }

        rv := pod.GetResourceVersion()

        switch event.Type {
        case apiWatch.Added:
            fmt.Printf("- %v: %s [%s]\n", event.Type, pod.GetName(), rv)
        case apiWatch.Modified:
            fmt.Printf("- %v: %s [%s]\n", event.Type, pod.GetName(), rv)
        case apiWatch.Deleted:
            fmt.Printf("- %v: %s [%s]\n", event.Type, pod.GetName(), rv)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Furthermore, if I remove the code to skip "old" events, then I see ADDED events for all running pods?" Pretty sure that is expected -- you have asked to watch all pods, so you will initially receive notifications for all existing pods so that your application is aware that they exist. E.g., try running `kubectl get pod -w` and you'll see it start with a list of existing pods.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for your answer. But why are events duplicated? If you run my code, you will see the same `ADDED` events multiple times :(